# How exactly does clan earn XP?

Tags: clash-of-clans

How exactly does a clan get XP? From what [I've read](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Perks) it is only awarded through participation in war. I don't understand the comment "The stronger target is, the more XP the Clan will receive" so does it mean if a player attacks a much weaker base they will get 0 stars or 1 stars or what? In such a case would it matter if they win with 1 star or 3? Does this mean, you get more XP for attacking a much stronger base and getting at least 1 star? I ask because this would be a good strategy provided that the war isn't close.

I'm thinking of strategies to make best use of of the 3x XP event that's coming up and want to make sure I understand how the XP system works. So far all I can think of is just make wars larger. (btw my clan sucks at war and almost always looses, due to individual player's poor attack strategy).

Comment: as i remember its like this... the more player participate in the war the more xp it gains. there is no other way for it to gain XP. also winning gives a boost to the xp

Answer (score 2):

According to this Supercell [forum post](https://forum.supercell.com/showthread.php/567168-Full-information-on-Clan-Levels-and-Perks), Clan XP is earned by destroying enemy war bases (getting at least one star on a base), getting 40&60% of available war stars, and by winning the war. The total amount of clan XP available in a war depends *only* on the number of players in the war.

Answer (score -2):

I think the way my clan gains exp is by doing clan v clan and you dont have to win them you just have to be in it but if you win you will get more exp

Comment: Is this the only way?

Comment: I noticed now it says how much XP you win when you select a particular base. What I'm unsure about is how well you need to do to get the xp e.g. 1 star?

Answer (score -2):

Clan games also give your clan a lot of xp as an alternative to clan wars that you must win to achieve more xp.